# eCommerce store logout is not redirecting to shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

friends, I am facing a problem when a user logs out from my woo-commerce store it redirects to WordPress admin page but it must redirect to shop page.For your reference My store URL is www.pathankotmandi.com. Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy, solution can be added inside your functions.php file which can be found in the root directory of your theme:

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
    exit();
}
```

What this will do is hook onto the wp_logout hook and redirect the user to the shop page after logging out. Hope this works! Good luck!

Comment: thanks, bro it worked for me..there is an extra semicolon after shop.

Comment: Happy to hear! Woops! I actually wrote the solution on my mobile device. Will fix that now, thanks for letting me know!